# Find changed properties of a class

Tags: c#

I am using asp.net 3.5

I have a license class containing 10 properties and not marked as serializable. I have to log property changes to the database. License is an entity class,and it is not in my scope to modify it. So I cannot mark it as serializabel neither i can use IpropertyChanged Interface.

Now i cannot store it in viewstate as it is not serializable. I wanted to store it so that i can compare it with new values and see which value has changed.

How to proceed with this.

Comment: Are you using LINQ2SQL?  If so, it has some methods to deal with that.

Comment: No we are not using LINQ2SQL.We are using enterprise library and populating our entities in DAL.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by writing a class that looks at a target object and uses reflection to store the value of all it's exposed properties in a Name / Value dictionary. Then, at "Compare" time, you use reflection again and compare to the values stored in your dictionary?

Just a guess...

Answer (score 1):

If you have the original object (ie. before it was changed). Then it might be best to use reflection to loop through the exposed properties and compare them.

Your code will probably end up looking something like this (this isn't a full sample):

```
Type type = license.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
foreach(PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
//compare your properties with property.GetValue(newLicense, null) and property.GetValue(originalLicense, null);
}
```

Then you can store, or do whatever you want with the different columns.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the given answers you could have a look at Aspect Oriented Programming (for example PostSharp: http://www.sharpcrafters.com/ ).

This way you can create an method outside the class that gets called each time a property gets set. After a diff any changes can be inserted into the database